# Центральное ядро — корректно ли словосочетание?

Tags: тавтология

Корректна ли фраза "центральное ядро"? По сути же ядро не может быть не в центре?

Answer (score 1):

```
 По сути же ядро не может быть не в центре?
```

Почему не может? может быть просто внутри, но не в центре, а сдвинуто.

Центральное ядро - это научный термин, так что сомневаться в корректности не приходится:

> Центральное ядро – ядро миндалевидного тела. Оно получает сенсорную
> информацию из первичной чувствительной зоны коры головного мозга,
> ассоциативной коры и таламуса. От него нервные волокна идут к
> гипоталамусу, среднему мозгу, варолиевому мосту и продолговатому
> мозгу. Центральное ядро участвует в координировании различных
> компонентов, составляющих выражение эмоциональных реакций.

Ядер много, есть термин вторичное ядро:

> ВТОРИЧНОЕ ЯДРО — диплоидное ядро, расположенное в центре зародышевого
> мешка и образующееся в результате слияния двух гаплоидных ядер,
> которые сходятся к центру с полюсов.

https://psychology_pedagogy.academic2.ru/20223/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1

Есть много ядер в анатомической терминологии:

> Промежуточное [[Кахаля]] ядро  , nucleus interstitialis [[Cajal]]. Расположено с латеральной стороны от ядра глазодвигательного нерва, от  которого отделяется медиальным продольным пучком.
>
> 2. Ядра покрышки  , nuclei tegmenti (tegmentales). Входят в состав ретикулярной формации среднего мозга. Расположены дорсально от ядра
>    блокового нерва и вентральнее медиального продольного пучка.
> 3. Красное ядро  , nucleus ruber. Расположено между черным веществом и substantia grisea centralis. В его состав входят нейроны с железосодержащим пигментом, на которых заканчиваются волокна от коры большого мозга, таламуса и мозжечка.
> 4. Внутриножковое ядро  , nucleus endopeduncularis. Группа нейронов, расположенная у средней линии внутри ножки мозга сразу после вступления в основание большого
>    мозга. Это ядро, вероятно, входит в состав проводящего пути, соединяющего бледный шар и ретикулярную формацию.

https://www.bsmu.by/page/51/2152/

Так что центральное ядро не звучит как плеоназм, избыточности здесь нет.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, корректна. В случае, если ядер несколько,  можно выделить и левое, и верхнее, и южное... Следовательно, и центральное.